# How to properly load CSS from an external module in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, webpack.config.js

In my react.js app I am trying to use an external module [(React Toastify)](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify)
using the following statement:

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

Unfortunately this throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .Toastify__toast-container {
|   z-index: 9999;
```

I guess it has something to do with webpack, here are my settings in webpack.config.js:

```
    output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
},

devtool: production ? '' : 'source-map',

resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
},


module: {
  rules: [
    {
     test: /\.jsx?$/,


      exclude: /node_modules/,



      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  ],
},
```

};

I am not sure how this can be fixed, any advice appreciated.

Comment: You need to add css loader to webpack plugins

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Ah, of course - I was using a boilerplate where it wasnt declared. Now it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpack config file you have add the css loader test:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    },
  ],
},
```

And don't forget to install it with `npm i -D css-loader`.

More info here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader